# How to do different things with subclasses based on subclass type with using instanceof?

Tags: java, oop

I have an abstract class A and two subclasses B and C.

In some other class I have a list of instances of A's ie: List. The list of A's could of course contain elements that could be instances of B or C.

If the instance is B, I want to add it to table A which resides in Class D.
If the instance is C, I want to add it to table B which also resides in Class D.

Is this possible without using instanceof?

Comment: as @Ross explained, yes it's possible, but you'll have to get each element of your list and call the method. It's not automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list `L : List<A>` which contains `B extends A` and `C extends A`. While you fetch elements `E` from `L` you like to add `E` to `D.A` if `E instanceof B` or add `E` to `D.B` if `E instanceof C`.

Use the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) by providing an abstract method `A.visit(D)`. `B.visit(D)` would implement it by calling `D.addMeToTableA(this)` while `C.visit(D)` would implement it by calling `D.addMeToTableB(this)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, put a method in A which you override in B and C containing the table name.

Comment: In this case, you would be coupling A (and B and C) with the table names and the separation algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here could be a solution:

```java
public abstract class A {
    public abstract void addTo(D d);
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void addTo(D d) {
        d.addB(this);
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    @Override
    public void addTo(D d) {
        d.addC(this);
    }
}
```

A simple D class:

```java
public class D {
    public void addB(B b) {
        // ...
    }
    public void addC(C c) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then:

```java
List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
list.add(new B());
list.add(new C());

D d = new D();
for (A a : list) {
    a.addTo(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to let B and C return some discriminator to let the class that moves stuff from the list into D's tables know to which table they should be added, but you'll eventually get to a point where you need a switch or something like that.

Example:

```
public enum TypeOfA { TYPE_1, TYPE_2 }

public abstract class A {
    // your other stuff
    public abstract TypeOfA getType();
}

public class B extends A {
    public TypeOfA getType() {
        return TypeOfA.TYPE_1;
    }
}

public class Sorter {
    public void putInTables() {
         for (final A a: this.listOfAs()) {
             this.getTableFor(a).add(a);
         }
    }

    private Table getTableFor(final A a) {
        switch(a.getType()) {
             case TypeOfA.TYPE_1: return tableA;
             case TypeOfA.TYPE_2: return tableB;
        }
    }
}
```

With this solution, you could add more sub-classes of A that share the same type of "discriminator" with B or C, so your sorter class will put their instances in the same tables.

Apart from that, you keep the actual decission in the Sorter's logic, and if TYPE_1 and TYPE_2 have some semantic meaning, B and C don't actually have to know why they expose it.

Answer (score 0):

"How to do different things with subclasses based on subclass type", or in other words: polymorphism. Off course is possible, its one of the main principles of OO software. And you don't need to use instanceOf, .getClass or others forms of meta-programing for solving a basic OO problem.

You can have an abstract method in A like:

```
public String belongsToTable() {}
```

in A you implement in one way in B you implement in another way.

Off course its probably a bad name and off course returning a string is probably a bad idea, its only an example based in your A,B,C problem. Software development its about naming and semantic, the next time please use meaningful names if you really want good advice and no a generic advice that you can find in a basic OO book.